# using a series as markersize in python plt.plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Is it possible to use a column in a dataframe to scale the marker size in matplotlib? I keep getting an error about using a series when I do the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_dict = {'Vx': [16,25,85,45], 'r': [1315,5135,8444,1542], 'ms': [10,50,100, 25]}
df= pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20, 10))
ax.plot(df.Vx, df.r, '.', markersize= df.ms)
```

when I run

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I'm guessing it does not like the fact that Im feeding a series to the marker, but there must be a way to make it work...

Comment: unfortunately, it only accepts floats, not series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to use the built-in scatter plot function in `pandas` where you can pass a whole series object as the size param to vary the bubble size:

```
df.plot.scatter(x=['Vx'], y=['r'], s=df['ms'], c='g')  # df['ms']*5 bubbles more prominent
```

[image]

---

Or, if you want to go via the `matplotlib` route, you need to pass a scalar value present in the `series` object each time to the `markersize` arg.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
[ax.plot(row['Vx'], row['r'], '.', markersize=row['ms']) for idx, row in df.iterrows()]
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use [`plt.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html) instead of `plt.plot`. Scatter lets you specify the size `s` as well as the color `c` of the points using a tuple or list.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_dict = {'Vx': [16,25,85,45], 'r': [1315,5135,8444,1542], 'ms': [10,50,100, 25]}
df= pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20, 10))
ax.scatter(df.Vx, df.r, s= df.ms)
plt.show()
```